# jQuery multiple animations flicker

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousewheel

I have the following jQuery code in a WordPress theme a freelancer developed for me a while back, this particular snippet is executed during pagination, once the next page is loaded, `filtered` is used to select the newly loaded elements, and then this code is used to show it sliding down and then scrolls to the top of the newly added element.

```
    jQuery(filtered).hide();                            
    jQuery(filtered).slideToggle('normal', function() {
        var pos = jQuery(filtered).offset().top+'px';       
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: pos}, 800);
    });
```

It works fine and looks good, but the problem is, once it scrolls up, and if I use the mousewheel to scroll it down, it just don't happen for a few seconds. It kind of gets stuck/flicker before it can scroll down, What is being done wrong here, is it possible for the code to be improved ?

Comment: Please add a jsFiddle example demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Why do you call it "multiple animations"? I can only see one (scrolling up).

Comment: call .stop() on the previous animation and call the current animation in jQuery to avoid flickering while doing serial animations.